# NSNotification.Name.frameDidChangeNotification not found

Tags: macos, notifications, nsview

What is the current path of frameDidChangeNotification (and  boundsDidChangeNotification, I assume) ?

The *NSView.postsFrameChangedNotifications* and *NSView.postBoundsChangeNotifications* properties are available, but compiler does not find *NSNotification.Name.frameDidChangeNotification* and *NSNotification.Name.boundsDidChangeNotification* (tried also Notification.Name.xxx - same result), even though AppKit is imported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`frameDidChangeNotification` is a class property of `NSView`: `NSView.frameDidChangeNotification`.